# Why am i getting a "In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<Fctor()>’ " error

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm just getting started with multi-threading in `C++ 11` and I stumbled upon an error that I do not understand.

This is my `multi1.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
class Fctor {
public:
    void operator() (string msg) {
        std :: cout  << "From Fctor: "<< msg << std :: endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    string s = "Hello world";
    std::thread t1((Fctor()),s);

    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Now I try to run this file in a `cygwin` environment using the following command:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 multi1.cpp -o output
```

This leads to an error in compilation that prints:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/thread:39:0,
                 from multi1.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<Fctor()>’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/thread:137:47:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = Fctor&; _Args = {}]’
multi1.cpp:15:19:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/functional:1665:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<Fctor()>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/functional:1695:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<Fctor()>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
```

I cannot comprehend what the compiler is trying to tell me. I am trying to understand how things work while I go through the [C++ multithreading tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2nMqNj7vxE&index=2&list=PL5jc9xFGsL8E12so1wlMS0r0hTQoJL74M) on YouTube by Bo Qian.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Compiles fine with GCC 4.9.2 on Ubuntu

Comment: I tried it on `cmd` after I updated my `PATH` environment variable on Windows to point to the bin folder of the `gcc` installation and it compiles fine.It's probably something wrong with my `cygwin` installation

Comment: [Works on gcc on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93faa79b53039b26) although I had to remember to give it the `-pthread` option.

Comment: Are you sure this is your actual code? All the deduced types are completely wrong. These errors correspond to something along the lines of `Fctor f;
std::thread t1(f);`

Comment: The code is OK, and compiles everywhere. Parenthises around Fctor() suggest that the code was different, because they are not needed there.